# Excel VBA efficient way to compare two 2D arrays

Tags: arrays, performance, excel, lookup, vba

I have two 2D arrays (lets call them A and B) both containing serial numbers at element 0 and dates at element 1. Many of the serial numbers in A are found in B(about 60%). Where there is a match I need to check if the corresponding date in array B is less than the date in array A, if so then set the date in A to null.

Currently I'm using a loop within a loop:

```
For x = 0 To UBound(arrayA)

    For y = 0 To UBound(arrayB)

        If arrayB(y, 0) = arrayA(x, 0) Then ' the serial numbers match

            If arrayB(y, 1) < arrayA(x, 1) Then ' test the dates

                arrayA(x, 1) = Null

            End If

            Exit For

        End If

    Next y

Next x
```

This works fine but is slow (around 30 - 40 seconds) so I've been trying to devise other methods, some of them quite wacky such as

```
dateB = application.Vlookup(arrayB, arrayA(x), 1, false
```

which takes twice as long and you need to handle the not found errors.

I've tried creating two one dimensional arrays (serials, dates) instead of the 2D arrayB and using application.match to provide an index to the date but this again takes about twice as long to complete. Finally I've tried writing the data to a worksheet, getting the dates via vlookup & comparing them but this is no faster & isn't really what I want.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: It's slow because you are looping through everything every time. If you have <30K rows, you can use INDEX and MATCH. If not, use a dictionary object; the latter's uique index will cut this down to a minimum.

Comment: How did you populate he arrays? Typically, grabbing hte .Value2 from the worksheet creating a 2D array that is one-based, not zero-based.

Comment: I had no idea VBA had a dictionary class, thanks! That should solve the problem nicely, I'll work on it later this afternoon. Regarding populating - the arrays are zero based, I fed them to the arrays in loops on various worksheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some framework to compare dates based on serial numbers.

```
Sub dictCompare()
    Dim a As Long, arrA As Variant, arrB As Variant, dictB As Object
    Debug.Print Timer

    Set dictB = CreateObject("scripting.Dictionary")
    dictB.comparemode = vbTextCompare

    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        With Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("A:B"))
            arrA = .Cells.Value2
        End With
    End With

    With Worksheets("sheet2")
        With Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("A:B"))
            arrB = .Cells.Value2
        End With
        For a = LBound(arrB, 1) + 1 To UBound(arrB, 1) 'LBound(arrB, 1)+1 to skip the column header label
            dictB.Item(arrB(a, 1)) = arrB(a, 2)
        Next a
    End With

    For a = LBound(arrA, 1) + 1 To UBound(arrA, 1) 'LBound(arrA, 1)+1 to skip the column header label
        If dictB.exists(arrA(a, 1)) Then
            If dictB.Item(arrA(a, 1)) > arrA(a, 2) Then _
                arrA(a, 2) = vbNullString
        End If
    Next a

    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(arrA, 1), UBound(arrA, 2)) = arrA
    End With
    Debug.Print Timer
End Sub
```

Adjust the worksheets and ranges as appropriate. While timed results are very subjective, this takes ~¹⁄₃ second on 30K rows of random data in both Sheet1 and Sheet2.

Comment: Ha, you even saved me the coding, brilliant! many thanks. In case others are looking for this solution and missed our earlier comments I didn't know dictionaries were available in VBA, this is a perfect solution.

Comment: The one important item to note is the way I populate the dictionary from arrB. This is the 'overwrite' method. If you have duplicate serial numbers, the last occurrence (and its date) is the one that is retained. If the dates are not sorted and a second occurrence could have a date that is earlier than the first, then `If dictB.Exists` should be checked before loading and if it previously exists, only the latest date should be retained.

Comment: No duplicates but thanks for the tip, I'll remember to check the dictionary before adding if this is a risk in future